# Why does the compiler emit a stloc followed by a ldloca?

Tags: il

While I was trying to understand what Round actually does I ended up looking at the IL of a simple console program (emitted from the C# .NET 4.5 compiler):

```
.maxstack  2
.locals init (float64 V_0,
         float64 V_1)
IL_0000:  ldc.r8     2.0001232314135344
IL_0009:  stloc.0
IL_000a:  ldloca.s   V_0
IL_000c:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Double::ToString()
IL_0011:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0016:  ldloc.0
IL_0017:  ldc.i4.5
IL_0018:  call       float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Round(float64,
                                                          int32)
IL_001d:  stloc.1
IL_001e:  ldloca.s   V_1
IL_0020:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Double::ToString()
IL_0025:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_002a:  ret
```

And I noticed the instructions on IL_001d and IL_001e. They seem redundant to me, storing the value in a local and loading the same value right after that. Removing them and reassembling the IL got me a NullReferenceException so I'm guessing there is some point to it. But I can't figure it out.

So where is the NullReferenceException coming from? And why does the compiler emit those two instructions?
There is no more IL than given above, except for some meta of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ldloca` loads the address of a variable onto the stack (not the variable itself). So, these two commands are not opposite: `stloc.1` pops the variable value, returned by `Math::Round`, and `ldloca.s` pushes on the stack address of `V_1`, required by `Double::ToString` call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After some more research based on your pointers I now completely get it. The 'call' opcode requires a reference to be pushed on the stack and pushing a double on the stack does not satisfy that requirement. So it needs to be stored in a variable and the reference of that variable is pushed on the stack so 'call' is happy. And I think the NullReferenceException occurs because there's nothing at the address indicated by double value.

Comment: I think that exception type in this case depends on the current value on the top of the stack: it may be anything from NullReferenceException, printing junk to access violation.

Comment: Regarding `System.Double::ToString` call, this is instance method, it expects the address of `Double` structure on the stack. Since `double` variable has the same memory layout as `Double` structure, this makes `ToString` method happy. And, by the way, this code shows, that calling `ToString` for `int, double` and similar types doesn't cause boxing.